# Multiple PID Files in newsyslog.conf

Tags: bsd, logrotate, openbsd, syslog-ng

In the newsyslog.conf file you can define a PIDFile for each log file being rotated. What I'm wondering is can you define (2) two pid_files per logfile being rotated?

--
/var/log/file.log root:group 644 7 * $D0 GZ /var/run/fileA.pid;/var/run/fileB.pid

If yes, would it just be a semicolon that separates the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of listing multiple PIDfiles, you can list
multiple pkill  separated by a semicolon.

Example
/var/log/file.log root:group 644 7 * $D0 GZ "pkill -HUP processName1; pkill -HUP processName2"